# How do you address this warning - "You have reached your question limit"

Tags: support

I am seeing this? I don't have a lot of questions that I have asked. Would an admin have to look at this and reset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the message you get when the system raised a question ban on your account. Moderators cannot do anything to lift it, or reset it.

All you can do to lift it is described in [Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans)

Comment: That is quite interesting. All of my questions were asked against specific problems that I ran into. I typically go and update questions when I have more information that I get through the process of answering those questions. So this looks like a rabbit hole to me. I consider myself an active contributor who does not need a lot of incentive to contribute. If systems like this are designed to turn away even people like me it would definitely be worth looking at the system itself.

Comment: For users who are question banned, writing good answers helps in lifting the question ban.

Comment: Thanks @kiamlaluno for the guidance on this. I believe I have tried to answer 4x the number of questions as I have asked again based on problems that I ran into. Going back and improving content should really be based on some feedback. I suspect people would not end up wanting to do that given that the reason why you are on the site is because you have a question that you are trying to get an answer for. Given that the answer to the question would be more pressing, and the solution to the question ban quite vague, people would just leave.

Comment: Would be quite interesting to see how many people who got question banned came back and addressed their question ban.

Comment: Thanks for the edits on my question @leymannx. It looks like the question ban was revoked. Thanks also to all those who + voted some of the past questions.